# Passing records to ffi

Tags: fay

When I pass a record to javascript, it works:

```
data Record = Record {
  elem :: String
}
doSomethingForeign :: Record -> Fay ()
doSomethingForeign = ffi " callJsFun(%1) "
```

But when the function is not monomorphical, the record is not evaluated, one needs to do it manually:

```
class Passable a
instance Passable Record
instance Passable Text
doSomethingForeign' :: (Passable a) => a -> Fay ()
doSomethingForeign' = ffi " callJsFun(Fay$$_(%1)) "
```

This is the simple case, when the extra typing of `Fay$$_` isn't that annoying, but if I pass more complex structures with type parameters to js, then adding just `Fay$$_` won't solve it. I'd like to know the rule, when the evaluation to native js types is applied and where not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thunks will remain and type conversions won't happen if you have a type variable or `Ptr X` in the FFI, in contrast to a concrete type or `Automatic a` where the opposite applies.

I think what you want here is `:: Passable a => Automatic a -> Fay ()` to force any thunks. It should be equivalent to separating this into two functions with a monomorphic argument. Using `Automatic` with a foreign type such as `Text` will only force the thunk and not do any type conversions.